# Pinterest button is not catching 'Click' event

Tags: javascript, jquery, pinterest

This is the code for a simple pinterest button.

```
<div class="myPinterestButton">
     <a href="//www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.flickr.com%2Fphotos%2Fkentbrew%2F6851755809%2F&media=http%3A%2F%2Ffarm8.staticflickr.com%2F7027%2F6851755809_df5b2051c9_z.jpg&description=Next%20stop%3A%20Pinterest"    
         data-pin-do="buttonPin" 
         data-pin-config="none">
          <img src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pinit_fg_en_rect_gray_20.png" />
    </a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" async src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

None of the content is iframed. The pinterest button ends up being the `<a>` tag with some additional data attributes (thanks to the `pinit.js` which adds it at runtime).

Here's the thing I don't undrestand. If I click the button it works fine. But if I want to trigger a click on it (for example click a different element on the page and use jQuery to do `$(".myPinterestButton a").trigger("click")` it doesn't work.

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h42vK/2/

What's going on here please?

Comment: it is triggering in jsfiddle

Comment: You mean you are getting the pinterest popup if you click the black square?

Comment: i can see in log that event occured

Comment: OP wants clicking the black square to trigger it.

Comment: Yeah the event may have ocurred - but the problem is that the Pinterest popup isn't showing up... It's as though Pinterest's button,  the `<a>` tag is being clicked programatically but nothing is showing up

Comment: Triggering click doesn't call the `href` on an anchor as many people, including myself, assume it would. It feels weird and wrong that it doesn't but that's why it's not working.

Comment: I don't think it's to do with the href attribute. If you take a look at the markup in the DOM, the pinterest button actually doesn't have an HREF assigned to it. It gets removed, and instead the url is assigned to a 'data-pin-href' attribute (or something similar)

Comment: Yes but that href gets removed at runtime? I had a read from the link you gave me. But if the `<a>` has no href after the page is loaded doesn't that pretty much make the `<a>` equivalent to an ordinary `<div>`?

Comment: That's correct. The way Pinterest button works is that you give an href to the `<a>`. However you also include an external Script by Pinterest (see the external scripts section on the fiddle). One of the things that external script does is it removes the href from the a and assigns the URL to the data-pin-href attr.

Comment: Ah okay there's pinterest JS there that fiddles with it. Look at how it creates the popup window and either duplicate that, or if you're lucky, they might have set up a listener that you *can* trigger.

Comment: You mean debug the minified version of their JS? Sounds like a mission... I could dive in but before I do, I was wondering if there are any common reasons for why a `.trigger("click")` may not be working in this scenario?

Comment: Not much to debug really. `window.open($(".myPinterestButton a").data('pin-href'));`

Comment: Ok the reason it doesn't work is that the `click` set up on the button uses the mouse event - I've added `console.log(a)` to pinterest's `click` function. Look at the difference. Could be fixable. http://jsfiddle.net/h42vK/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can use click event for wrapper div .myPinterestButton instead .myPinterestButton a

```
$(".myPinterestButton").trigger("click")
```